# Return lowest number contained in structures with an identical parameter

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm a beginner with very basic knowledge in scheme and have a bit of trouble with understanding how to solve an exercise. Given a similar to the following list of structures:

```
(define-struct swimmer (name country time))

 (define list-swimmers
  (list
   (make-swimmer "Hans" 'Germany 187.34)
   (make-swimmer "Fred" 'USA 209.12)
   (make-swimmer "Bianca" 'France 192.01)
   (make-swimmer "Adolf" 'Germany 186.79)
```

I have to create a procedure that consumes the name of a country and the name of a list and produces the best time out of every swimmer from that country and another procedure which consumes a list of countries and produces a result with the countries, followed by the best respective time i.e

```
(listof swimmer) (listof symbol) -> (listof (list symbol number))
```

I'm having a lot of trouble with the exercise and so far only managed to write a procedure which checks if a country name exists in the list and returns true/false:

```
(define (contains-country? c a-list-of-swimmers)
  (cond
     [(empty? a-list-of-swimmers) false]
     [(cons? a-list-of-swimmers) 
      (cond
        [(symbol=? (swimmer-country (first a-list-of-swimmers))c) true]
        [else 
          (contains-country? c  (rest a-list-of-swimmers))])]))

(define (best-time-by-country (contains-country? c a-list-of-swimmers)))
```

I have no clue where I should go from here. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does defining a `runner` struct allow you to call `make-swimmer`?

Comment: Oops, that's a leftover from a template I used. Thanks for pointing it out, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exercise is quite easy to solve with  the basic `map`, `filter`, and `apply` procedures:

```
(define (best-of slist country)
  (apply min               ; take the minimum
         (map swimmer-time ; of the times
              (filter      ; from every entry from the selected country
               (lambda (s) (eq? country (swimmer-country s))) 
               slist))))

(best-of list-swimmers 'Germany)
=> 186.79
```

and, building on that:

```
(define (best-of-list slist countries)
  (map 
   (lambda (c) (list c (best-of slist c))) 
   countries))

(best-of-list list-swimmers '(USA France))
=> '((USA 209.12) (France 192.01))
```

**EDIT**

Given that you need to use the "Beginning Student with List Abbreviations" language in Racket which I am not familiar with, I've skimmed through the relevant doc and came up with this; I hope this is somehow in line with what you've been taught:

```
(define (best-of-helper slist country max-value)
  (if (null? slist) 
      max-value
      (if (eq? country (swimmer-country (car slist)))
          (best-of-helper (cdr slist) 
                          country 
                          (if (number? max-value)
                              (min max-value (swimmer-time (car slist)))
                              (swimmer-time (car slist))))
          (best-of-helper (cdr slist) country max-value))))

(define (best-of slist country)
  (best-of-helper slist country #f))

(best-of list-swimmers 'Germany)
=> 186.79
```

and

```
(define (best-of-list slist countries)
  (if (null? countries)
      '()
      (cons 
       (list (car countries) (best-of slist (car countries))) 
       (best-of-list slist (cdr countries)))))

(best-of-list list-swimmers '(USA France))
=> (list (list 'USA 209.12) (list 'France 192.01))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for offering a solution. While it seems to work, I'm afraid it is using functions we have not yet covered in our course. We were instructed to use Beginning Student with List Abbreviations as a language of choice if that rings any bells. It appears that we have to use more primitive ways to solve the problem as functions such as `apply` require being defined.